# How to delete child entities when updating a parent entity in EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This is my entities:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; } = new List<Answer>();
    public TimeSpan TimeForAnswer { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

If I update just my parent entity:

```
public void Update(Question entity)
{
    _dbContext.Questions.Update(entity);
}
```

EF will add/update child entities, but not delete if any missing. I searched, and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73054066/how-to-remove-child-entities-from-parent-collection-on-parent-update-in-entity-f). And modified my method like this:

```
public void Update(Question entity)
{
    var existingParent = _db.Questions
        .Include(p => p.Answers)
        .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == entity.Id);
        
    if (existingParent != null)
    {
        existingParent.Answers.Clear();
    }

    _db.Questions.Update(entity);
}
```

And now I 'am getting this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Question' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: `Update` doesn't update objects. It tells the DbContext to attach an object that didn't come from it, and track it in the `Modified` state. All changes are persisted when `SaveChanges` is called in a single database transaction

Comment: If the object is *already* tracked, because it was loaded by EF itself, you'll get an error. Why are you using `Update` like this? Did you try to follow some "repository best practices" that shows this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to:

```
_db.Questions.Update(entity);
```

tries to start tracking entity, but it's already being tracked by the query:

```
var existingParent = _db.Questions
    .Include(p => p.Answers)
    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == entity.Id);
```

I'd go for:

```
public void Update(Question entity)
{
    var existingParent = _db.Questions
        .Include(p => p.Answers)
        .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == entity.Id);
        
    if (existingParent != null)
    {
        // Update Parent Entity Properties
        existingParent.Text = entity.Text;
        existingParent.TimeForAnswer = entity.TimeForAnswer;
        existingParent.TestId = entity.TestId;
        // remove existing from tracked Question
        existingParent.Answers.Clear();
        // add answers from Question in method param
        existingParent.Answers.AddRange(entity.Answers);
    }
    else
    {
        // Add the question with answers to the db
        _db.Questions.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: One could argue that the method shouldn't be called `Update` but use a name that actually describes what it does, eg `StoreWithoutAnswers`. I suspect `Update` was used to follow some "repository" article

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ... 100%!  But given where OP is starting from, the answer (plus your first comment on original question) seems the best advice to stepwise improve understanding of how EF works.

Comment: But how do i update parent entity in same method?

Comment: OMG, I 'am stupid, sorry for bothering.

Comment: No problem.  Key learning from this is that updating a simple object can be done using the `DbContext.Questions.Update` method, but this will not work when you have a graph of nested objects.  EF does not know what items you removed from a child collection because it is never tracking them when you just use the Update method.  You need to get them from dB and then Remove them from child collection for EF to detect the removal.